# Why numeric_limits<int>::min() is differently defined?

Tags: c++, stl

To retrieve the smallest value i have to use `numeric_limits<int>::min()`

I suppose the smallest int is -2147483648, and tests on my machine showed this result.
But some C++ references like [Open Group Base Specifications](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html) and
[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/) define it with the value -2147483647.

I ask this question because in my implementation of the negaMax Framework (Game Tree Search)
the value *minimal integer* * (-1) has to be well defined.
Yes, with *minimal int* = (numeric_limits::min() + 2) i am on the safe side in any case,
thus my question is more theoretically but i think nevertheless quite interesting.

Comment: Why not ask what the maximum integer is, and multiply that by -1 to get the effective minimum for your purposes?

Comment: In two-s compliment, the absolute value of the maximum integer is 1 greater than the minimum integer

Comment: @Anon: Thanks, this is better then my idea (minimal int + 2)

Comment: @tzenes: I must disagree, in two complements, the absolute value of the minimum is one bigger than the maximum (i.e. -128..127 for 8 bits)

Comment: What tzenes said. Wish I could mod down a comment.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas is right. Thats two mistakes I've made in one day. Clearly I need more caffeine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a value is represented as sign-and-magnitude instead of two's complement, the sign bit being one with all other bits as zero is equivalent to -0. In sign-and-magnitude the maximum positive integer and negative integer are the same magnitude. Two's complement is able to represent one more negative value because it doesn't have the same symmetry.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `numeric_limits<int>::min()` is defined by implementation. That's why it could be different. You shouldn't stick to any concrete minimal value.

Comment: This. In practice it's often defined by machine architecture, but you could make a standard-conforming compiler that did it's own bit twiddling to represent negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

On cplusplus.com you forgot to read the qualifier

min. magnitude*

- This is not necessarily the actual value of the constant in any particular compiler or system, it may be equal or greater in magnitude than this.

Answer (score 0):

From the cplusplus.com link you posted (emphasis mine):

> The following panel shows the different constants and their **guaranteed minimal magnitudes** (positive numbers may be greater in value, and negative numbers may be less in value). **Any particular compiler implementation may define integral types with greater magnitudes than those shown here**

Numeric limits are always system and compiler defined, try running with a 64bit compiler and system, you may see totally different numbers.

Comment: you are right, but for example min char need not to be defined as -127 on one machine and -128 on the other, this is not defined by the system (32bit or 64bit). So what is the reason for the difference?

Comment: Christian: as others have said, twos complement is not the only way to do arithmetic. Ones complement is another way of handling numbers, there the minimum value you store in a byte is -127, not -128 (and similarly for 16 bits, 32 bits, and 64 bits). The C++ standard is flexible about this for the types that are actually meant to represent numbers (i.e. short, int, and long), and thus provides a guarantee that can be satisfied by both ones complement and twos complement, even while most implementations actually make it one bigger thanks to the architecture dictating twos complement.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>c++ uses two-s compliment for signed integers.  Thus the smallest signed integer is defined by `100..00` (usually 32 bit).</strike>

Simply shifting `1<<(sizeof(int)*8-1)` should give you the smallest signed integer.

Obviously for unsigned integers, the smallest is 0.

edit: you can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)

edit2: apparently C++ doesn't necessarily use two-s compliment, my mistake

Comment: "c++ uses two-s compliment for signed integers" I don't think this is true. It's implementation defined.

Comment: @GMan: Quite. C++ will use whatever its hardware integer math units give it. If that happens to be *one's* compliment, then that's what it has.